# If a cell has two different GPCRs, how does the cell differentiate between the phosphorylation cascade caused by each?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, receptor

In my biochem course, we learned that GPCR receptors trigger a phosphorylation cascade, with the end result being a large amplification of the signal in the form of cAMP. We never studied any particular GPCR individually, but we were told that GPCRs always end in the formation of a large amount of cAMP, which will go on to phosphorylate key targets that achieve the end result.

My question is as follows: If there are two GPCRs on the same cell membrane (let's say GPCR-A and GPCR-B triggered by substrates A and B respectively), how does the cell "know" which GPCR triggered the phosphorylation cascade if the end result is the same (large amount of cAMP). In theory, couldn't substrate B bind to GPCR-B and cause a phosphorylation cascade identical to that of GPCR-A, thus triggering GPCR-A's cellular response?

Is there some deeper specialization/uniqueness to each type of GPCR receptor that we didn't cover in my course? Does each GPCR produce a slightly different cascade that ends in something similar, but not exactly cAMP? Or is there some restriction, like each cell limited to only one GPCR (I would find this surprising, if this is the case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it would be an oversimplification to say that GPCRs act only through increases in cytosolic cAMP. This is true for receptors coupled to Gs proteins, but there are other G proteins like Gi, Go and Gq which act differently [1].

Now, a cell *can* have receptors coupled to many different G proteins. Vascular smooth muscle, for instance, has Gs, Gi and Gq-coupled receptors [2]. Further, a cell can have different receptors coupling to G proteins of the same type (e.g., hepatocytes have glucagon and beta adrenergic receptors [3], which both couple to Gs).

In such situations, the effects of different hormones add up. The final effect is a function of the *total* cytosolic concentration of second messenger (e.g., cAMP). Thus glycogen breakdown in a hepatocyte depends on the overall effects of glucagon and epinephrine [3]. The hepatocyte has no way of 'knowing' which cAMP molecule was formed by which hormone.

**References**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterotrimeric_G_protein
2. https://cvphysiology.com/Blood%20Pressure/BP026
3. https://www.nature.com/articles/emm2015122

Comment: So, if cells have several different GPCRs of the same G-type but triggered by different substrates, the effects must be additive and can't be unique (i.e. the different substrates can't trigger entirely different cellular responses)?

Comment: @SullyChen No, I think. They can't be unique. Do you have any particular counter-example in mind?

Comment: I don't have a particular counter-example, but I can faintly remember a professor remarking that a single cell could have dozens (or hundreds? not quite sure) of GPCR proteins on its membrane, so I was curious if they were all duplicates of the same receptor or if they could possible all be unique. I think you've answered my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is the phenomenon of 'spatiotemporal signalling'. Basically, the cAMP or other signal is restricted in space, so that it can only activate certain proteins. It has recently been shown that GPCRs can create cAMP signalling domains of nanometer size. So very much the cell can tell which cAMP molecule was formed in response to each hormone. Its extremely complicated and researchers are only just beginning to understand the significance of such signalling, but just imagine, all these receptors being located to distinct regions of the cell (cholesterol rich lipid rafts in the plasma membrane, endosomes after internalisation, cilia), and that each downstream signalling molecule or protein can only get so far before being down-regulated. As such, you can get very distinct signalling paths between different GPCRs, even in the same cell. (It gets much more complicated but).

Comment: Excellent answer, but we do ask that answers for anything beyond basic textbook info contain sources/references to support what is written and allow avenues for follow up reading.